# ActiveSupport::Concern and alias_method_chain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is a small problem I have. Take note that this is a simplified example.
Let's say I have a class with several instance methods and I want to log one of the instance methods using a `ActiveSupport::Concern`:

```
class Car
  include LogStartEngine

  def start_engine
    # useful thing
  end

  def check_oil
    # useful thing
  end

  def open_doors
    # useful thing
  end      
end
```

Here is what I first came up for the concern:

```
module LogStartEngine
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    alias_method_chain :start_engine, :logging
  end

  def start_engine_with_logging
    Rails.logger.info("Starting engine!")

    start_engine_without_logging

    Rails.logger.info("Engine started!")
  end
end
```

But this will lead to

```
  NameError: undefined method `start_engine' for class `Car'
    from /Users/david/.gem/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:32:in `alias_method'
```

This is understandable since when `LogStartEngine` is included, class `Car` doesn't have any method called `start_engine`.

I know I could solve this putting `include LogStartEngine` after method `start_engine` but I'd like to keep this statement where it is.

So the constraints are:

- log only the method `start_engine`, not all the methods.
- `Car` just need to include `LogStartEngine` concern. I'd like to avoid having to call any custom helper methods added by the concern, something like `log_method :start_engine`.
- I want to keep the `include LogStartEngine` statement where it is. I don't want it to be below method `start_engine` or at the end of the class.
- This is using Ruby 1.9. So `Module#prepend` is not a valid solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's old question, but I found an answer and I write for someone.

```rb
module LogStartEngine
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  define_method :start_engine_with_logging do
    Rails.logger.info("Starting engine!")
    start_engine_without_logging
    Rails.logger.info("Engine started!")
  end

  included do
    alias_method_chain :start_engine, :logging
  end
end
```

`define_method` is point of this approach, it defines method dynamically on included (before `alias_method_chain`)

Answer (score 1):

After some trials, here is my solution:

```
module LogStartEngine
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def method_added(_)
      unless instance_methods.include?(:start_engine_without_logging)
        alias_method_chain :start_engine, :logging
      end
    end
  end

  def start_engine_with_logging
    Rails.logger.info("Starting engine!")

    start_engine_without_logging

    Rails.logger.info("Engine started!")
  end
end
```

My sub question is: is there any other way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use delegation or use http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html - then you could compose your objects and combine them, also I assume you could use `method_missing` or something similar to provide an "automatic" logger.

```
class Car
  def start_engine
    # wrooom
  end
end

class CarWithLogging
  attr_reader :car

  def initialize(car)
    @car = car
  end

  def start_engine
    Rails.logger.info "starting engine"
    car.start_engine
    Rails.logger.info "engine started"
  end
end

car = CarWithLogging.new(Car.new)
car.start_engine
```

*Update*: As an alternative you could use Ruby's `prepend` (only available since 2.0), so actually AS::Concern is not required.

```
class Car
  prepend CarLogging
  def start_engine; end
end

module CarLogging
  def start_engine
    puts "before"
    super
    puts "after"
  end
end
```

Comment: As I said in the constraints, I'm using Ruby 1.9, so `prepend` is not an option but `Forwardable` is an interesting one.

Comment: Ah, my bad :) prepend would have been nice - I think then it's either `alias_method_chain` or `Forwardable`/Proxy...